# Selenium wait for jQuery.Masonry

Tags: java, jquery, selenium-webdriver, jquery-masonry

I am trying to wait until masonry has fully loaded with this code in Java

```
    String javaScript = "function defer() {"
                        +"if (window.jQuery.masonry)"
                        +"{ return true }"
                        +"else"
                        +"{ return false }"
                        +"}; defer()";

    boolean isMasonryLoaded=false;
    while(!isMasonryLoaded)
    {
        isMasonryLoaded = (boolean)(((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(javaScript));
    }
```

However i get NullPointerException at `while(!isMasonryLoaded)` 
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your script function `defer()` does not define before calling, you should try using `executeAsyncScript` as below :-

```
String javaScript = "var callback = arguments[0];"+
            "function defer() {if (window.jQuery.masonry){ "+
            "callback(true) }else{ callback(false) }}; defer()";

boolean isMasonryLoaded=false;
while(!isMasonryLoaded)
{
 isMasonryLoaded = (boolean)(((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeAsyncScript(javaScript));
}
```

Hope it helps..:)

Comment: thanks, it stopped NullPointerException, the js is not working properly though but that was not the matter of the question so thank you :)